# Post javascript object with nested properties to MVC

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4

I have an object defined in my application like so:

```
public class Request
{
  string LookupName { get; set; }
  PageData PageData { get; set; }
}

public class PageData
{
  int Page { get; set; }
  int PageSize { get; set; }
}
```

The action method looks something like this:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionMethod DoLookup(Request req)
{
  ...
  ...
  return new ContentResult(...);
}
```

I am trying to use JQuery + Javascript to post the information to the action, and everything is working great, except for the nested properties:

```
// javascript...
var reqData = {};
reqData.LookupName = "abc";
reqData.PageData= { Page:1, PageSize:10 };

$.post("/Controller/DoLookup", reqData, function(data) {
 ...
});
```

This works just great, and everything gets posted to the controller just fine, except for the nested properties in 'PageData'.  The PageData instance in Request seems to just be a default instance as both the Page and PageSize properties are 0.  If I omit 'PageData' in the javascript, then it will be null on the controller.

This seems a bit odd, because obviously MVC recognizes that there is some information for PageData, but seems to stop short of actually assigning the properties.  Is there something that I am doing wrong, or is there a way that I can find/use a custom model binder to get this working?

**NOTE:**
Please note that JSON is not mentioned anywhere here.  I am aware that I can convert tons of code + use JSON, etc.  This is a path I'd rather not address at this time unless that is the only possible option.

Comment: Is there any reason why you are using JS to submit the form instead of say a submit button?

Comment: In javascript, you're setting `req.PageRequest`, but the property name in c# is `PageData`.

Comment: @JasonP oops, that was a typo.  I fixed it.

Comment: This [question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/22059383/3383479) can help you

Comment: Not sure if that syntax is correct, I think it should be `reqData.PageData= { "Page":1, "PageSize":10 };` - note double quotes

Comment: @EkoostikMartin Either way is fine: http://jsfiddle.net/dErAb/

Comment: @A.R. I find the easiest way to deal with sending complex objects via ajax is to use json.

Comment: Try to stringify the object: `$.post("/Controller/DoLookup", JSON.stringify(reqData), function(data) {}, "json");`

Comment: @JasonP I stated in the question that I am trying to avoid JSON, except as a last resort.

Comment: +1 for JSON.stringify.  I understand you are trying to avoid JSON at this time but checking some code, I have a complex shopping cart object with nested objects I am successfully posting to MVC and I needed to use stringify.

Comment: @WilliamNewby That is great, but how am I (or anyone else) supposed to learn anything new if we just give up and use some other approach?  The question is about javascript objects, not json.

Comment: @A.R. while I think JSON is such a beautiful and fundamental thing to jump in to, I like your spirit a lot.  Let's leverage JSON.stringify for some learning. If indeed JSON.stringify works, rather than just blindly using it as  you are opposed to doing [which i appreciate], let's find out what it's doing.  We can throw together a fiddle and use both approaches and see how the string changes which can tell you how to adjust your own code without needing to include stringify itself.  I'll dig deeper with my own shoppingcart example

Comment: @WilliamNewby  I am already versed in JSON, and stringify, etc.  I know what it is doing, I know what I have to do on server side to handle it.  I'm wondering why / where the default MVC approach is falling short.

Comment: Create a .cshtml file, add a form, and add the fields to the page using `@Html.TextBoxFor()` (or similar, like `@Html.DropDownListFor()`, etc). Then let the form do a normal submit and compare the request to what is being sent via javascript. I imagine the field names won't be the same.

Comment: Generally when I want to use ajax, but I want to use the power of the mvc model binding, I'll do what I said in the previous comment, and get the data using `$(form).serialize()`. Here's an actual line of code from the project I'm working on: `$.post($form.attr('action'), $form.serialize()).done(function (response) {`. The reason I didn't go to that solution first is because you don't have a form in your example, so json is probably the best approach to take in that case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the Request $.post is putting together for you using fiddler, wireshark, etc.  The body of your post will be something like

```
LookupName=abc&PageData%5BPage%5D=1&PageData%5BPageSize%5D=10
```

where as if it is wrapped in Stringify, the server receives this

```
{"LookupName":"abc","PageData":{"Page":1,"PageSize":10}}
```

The interesting/frustrating thing here is asp.net MVC will try to deserialize the incoming data into your complex object in both cases.  But in the first case, it has no idea/fails with the child complex objects.

I have the same issue with a shopping cart object.  MVC will still get the properties of the main object just fine, but my child arrays/objects are null.

If you want to keep your front end code the same, then you need to write a custom deserializer on the back-end.  This seems like it could get messy fast.  As a fun experiment, change your end point to just receive a string and see what you end up with.

You can also write a web handler to intercept your incoming traffic before your controller to handle it yourself.

Comment: The frustrating thing here is that I'm sure you would like to here "this is what is going on in the guts of the .net mvc deserializer and why it understands json and not traditional form data".  I've done several searches for this and can only seem to find people just trying to override it.

Comment: Yeah, I dug around in the dis-assembly and discovered that this is just another shortcoming of MVC in general.  Anyhoo, I've fallen back to using an action filter that will deserialize json data.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create complex ViewModel.  Must create instance inside a constructor.  Here is the link to the answer. [Mvc Complex ViewModel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12713157/creating-view-models-consisting-of-objects-of-other-models-in-mvc3/12716033#12716033)

Comment: I don't think this is related.  Also, it doesn't work.